# SELECT records within GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Is the following possible?

I have 2 tables, for example:

**Location:**

```
Location_key | Location     | Site_key

           1 | First Floor  | 100
           2 | Second Floor | 100
           3 | Third Floor  | 100
           4 | Fourth Floor | 200
           5 | Fifth Floor  | 200
```

**Sub_Location:**

```
Sub_Location_key | Sub_Location | Location_key

               1 | Room A       | 1
               2 | Room B       | 2
               3 | Room C       | 3
               4 | Room D       | 1
               5 | Room E       | 2
```

I want to get all the sub locations within each location. So for example, if I'm getting site 100, I need to return something like:

```
First Floor
----------
Room A
Room D

Second Floor
----------
Room B
Room E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select l.Location, group_concat(Sub_Location)
from Location l
left outer join Sub_Location sl on l.Location_key = sl.Location_key
where l.Site_key = 100
group by l.Location
```

### edit

```
select l.Location, 
       group_concat(Sub_Location) as sublocations, 
       group_concat(a.name) as assets
from Location l
left outer join Sub_Location sl on l.Location_key = sl.Location_key
left outer join assets a on sl.sub_location_key = a.sub_location_key
where l.Site_key = 100
group by l.Location
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to go an extra level with this? I have an 'assets' table that's linked to the 'sub_location' table via the sub_location_key.

So could I return say:

First Floor
----------
Room A
   - Asset A
   - Asset B
Room D
   - Asset C
   - Asset D

Comment: See my edit. Maybe that works for you. If not you better ask another question with detailed description of your tables and requirements. And a prepared example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This should be close...

```
SELECT `Location`, `Sub_Location`
 FROM `Location` LEFT JOIN  `Sub_Location` 
 ON `Location_key`
GROUP BY `Location`
```

And you ought to read a bit about naming conventions e.g. you seem to be vaccilating terribly about which case to use.

Comment: I didn't create the database, (you should see the state of it!). Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @Ian LOL - we've all been there. The worst is when you're thinking, "This code is sh1te", and then realise that you wrote it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to your question, I think there is no need to use left-join, so the following natural-join version might be more suitable:
    SELECT l.Location, group_concat(Sub_Location)
    FROM Location l, Sub_Location sl
    WHERE l.Location_key = sl.Location_key ADN l.Site_key = 100
    GROUP BY l.Location